# Do in-line comments in C# code affect the compiled dll?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, comments

Consider a C# file with very little content e.g.

```
...
public void DoSomething()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Does Something!");
}
...
```

And the same snippet with a comment in it:

```
...
public void DoSomething()
{
    // This line does something!
    Console.WriteLine("Does Something!");
}
...
```

When the compiler comes along to put this file in a dll it will strip down the superfluous and make it machine-readable. Does this mean that both dll's are *entirely identical*? The two files obviously have a different number of lines and would hash to different values but does the compiler care? Would a blank line have the same impact of changing the file, e.g.

```
...
public void DoSomething()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Does Something!");
}
...
```

Comment: Not being funny, but you could have done it and tested it yourself, and already have an answer in the time it took to post the question.

Comment: When you compiled those three programs what happened?  Were they different, or not?

Comment: Just look at the IL and see yourself. Why should we do that for you?

Comment: If it's not a documentation comment, the compiler ignores it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171475/discussion-between-daisy-shipton-and-archer).

Comment: (Comments deleted; for discussion about how nice *or helpful* the other comments of "test it yourself" are, join the chat as linked.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that both dll's are entirely identical?

Maybe. There's a bit of subtlety here.

- By default, the C# compiler is not *deterministic*. That is, even with the exact same input, you could get different DLLs due to IDs being generated. I know there was a push towards making deterministic mode the default for .NET Core SDK projects, but I'm not sure whether that's happened. From the command line, just running csc with Roslyn 2.8.0.62830, `deterministic` is *not* the default
- Line numbers don't affect the IL usually, but they will affect any PDB files being generated, so that the debugger knows which line in the source code corresponds with what IL. Even without a change in line numbers, the PDB files contain a hash of the source code so that the debugger can check it's looking at the "right" code.
- Line numbers *can* have an effect anyway due to caller information attributes, as shown by the code below:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

  class Program
  {
      public static void Main()        
      {
          // Remove this comment and get a different result
          PrintLine();
      }

      static void PrintLine([CallerLineNumber] int line = 0)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(line);
      }
  }
  ```

With the comment there, this prints 9. Without the comment, it prints 8. The IL is different, as the line number is embedded there as a constant.

If you're concerned about comments affecting *performance*, you definitely shouldn't. But if you're really bothered about whether *any* change is possible just by making changes that wouldn't normally affect behavior - yes, there can be subtle changes.

Answer (score 2):

I used [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) to check that out for you (although I already knew that comments don't affect the generated IL).

```
public void Main()
{
    // Useful comment
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

and

```
public void Main()
{
    /* Useful comment */ Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

both compile to

```
public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

That's because compilers in general ignore comments unless they're documentation comments or you're generating debug symbols that require line numbers to work correctly.

Comment: "Not affecting the IL" isn't the same as "generating the same DLL". The compiler *could* decide to generate an ID based on the hash of all the source code; it wouldn't be in the textual IL used to decompile, but would still be relevant. Also note caller information attributes as per my answer.

Comment: @DaisyShipton As far as I know the .dll format includes a timestamp as well. So unless the files are compiled at the very same time, they're going to be different anyways.

Comment: Unless you use the `/deterministic` switch, yes. My point is that the OP asked whether the DLLs would be *entirely identical* - your answer doesn't really address that.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Because executable files under windows are never 
the same (since there is a `TimeDateStamp` in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`) I somewhat ignored that. Your answer seems to be more appropriate in addressing that question.